# react-router 2.0: # support in configuration

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I upgraded from react-router 0.13.x to 2.0. I noticed that react-router is no longer rendering the hashtag inside the urls. As a result, my routes aren't working anymore when directly visited.

If I try to place the hashtag directly in my configuration, it fails to match the url. How can I get react-router to render the hashtags? It used to do this by default in version 0.13.x.

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route name="foo" path="/foo" component={Foo}/>
                <Route name="bar" path="/bar" component={Bar}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the hashtag from `path`, this looks horrible. Your `browserHistory` needs to be a [`hashHistory`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-history-with-router) instead. It was the default to have a hashHistory before, now you need to specify it.

Also routes don't have a `name` anymore, and `path` uses no slash if you want to nest it in the /web/dist route. You should read the guide carefully again.

Comment: I will remove the hashtag, I just used to illustrate the url I needed. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I did not mean to remove it from the question, but from the code, sorry, you can put it back :)

Comment: It's still in there, it fails to match the url when I try to add the hashtag directly in the configuration. I kept it in there to help any future readers.